# Network Backup Configuration - telnetlib (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming, telnetlib

I Have the below script in python, the goal is to create a python script using telnet lib and backup a Cisco router configuration to an external file. However, every time I run this script it hangs. any help or recommendations would be much appreciated.

```
import telnetlib
import getpass
import time
import os


ip_add=raw_input('Please enter IP your would like to back up: ')
os.chdir('/Users/user/Backup_configuration/')

uname = raw_input('Please enter username for {} :'.format(ip_add))
print 'Please enter Password for {} :'.format(ip_add)
passwd = getpass.getpass()


connect = telnetlib.Telnet(ip_add)

connect.read_until('Username: ')
connect.write(uname+'\n')

connect.read_until('Password: ')
connect.write(passwd + '\n')

connect.write('config t\n hostname changed1\n end \n terminal len 0\n wr mem\n' )
time.sleep(3)

connect.write('show run\n')
out = connect.read_all()


filen= open('telnet_file.txt', 'w')
filen.write(out)
filen.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the timeout value, otherwise it would block the user input.
 Try following:

```
connect = telnetlib.Telnet(ip_add, 23, timeout=1)
```

[telnet lib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#module-telnetlib)